# Java hex string concatenate checksum

Tags: java, string, hex, concatenation, checksum

I want to send a hex message to a device with check sum in java.

```
    String msg = "\u0002\u0053\u003F\u0003";
    String checksum = "\u00EE";
    String last = "\u0004";
    msg = msg + checksum + last;
    sendmessage(msg);
```

If I hardcode the check sum as above it works. But if I insert check sum dynamically, it doesn't. This is what I have tried

```
String msg = "\u0002\u0053\u003F\u0003";
String checksum = String.format("\\u00%2X",238); // decimal 238 = Hex \u00EE
String last = "\u0004";
msg = msg + checksum + last;
sendmessage(msg) ; //getting invalid checksum because it is not inserted properly
```

Any directions please?

Comment: ...Please, for the love of Hermaeus Mora, fix your spelling issues! This is not a text message conversation, this is StackOverflow. All questions and answers should be in well-written, clear, correct English, with nifty little things like subjects and articles and proper capitalization ("**I** **w**ant to send **a** **h**ex message...") and no missing letters or extra spaces ("**I**f I hard **[no space]** code... ") and correct punctuation ("...it works **[no space]** , but if I...") and all that good stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\uxxxx` syntax is processed by the Java compiler, it is not literal.  It sounds like you want simply:

```
String msg = "\u0002\u0053\u003F\u0003";
char checksum = (char)238;
String last = "\u0004";
msg = msg + checksum + last;
sendmessage(msg);
```

Comment: @QPaysTaxes I thought about that, but ultimately that's up to sendmessage.  I eventually concluded String are being used (awkwardly) to hold a byte array.

Comment: @bkali  What is the best solution here. Now if the value is 1 (long var = 1 , cast to char as you suggested), it is not working. All I am trying to do is create a hex string with checksum . I am finding it hard. Initially I tried with 0x format, again concatenation was difficult there. Thanks for your directions

Comment: @user3124284 If you just want a hex-formatted string, use `Long.toString(var, 16)` or `String.format("%016x", var)`.  Your original post implied that you wanted to provide a checksum as literal character (byte?) in the String.  There is no way to pack a long in a single byte/char, but you could use `(char)(var >> 48) + (char)(var >> 32) + (char)(var >> 16) + (char)var` to pack into chars (or more/smaller shifts to pack into string-containing-byte), but I guess it's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @bkali, Sorry if I was not clear. This is what I am trying to do : message = new String( new byte[]{(byte)0x2,(byte)0x53} )

i = 1; // 0x31
checksum = 238 // 0xEE  ( checksum will always be <=256 )

message = message + i + checksum;

New message should be like this :
String( new byte[]{(byte)0x2,(byte)0x53, (byte)0x31, (byte)0xEE} )

Comment: @bkali not able to format it properly in comment section. any directions on how to do it in java.

Comment: @user3124284 To go back to your earlier comment "Now if the value is 1 (long var = 1 , cast to char as you suggested), it is not working", what isn't working?  The suggestion in my answer seems to match what you want.  (I'll say again that using a String to store a byte array is rather awkward.)

Comment: @bkali Thanks for answering, I really appreciate your patience. When I said it is not working, I meant the value is not populated as the corresponding hex value in the message. In the case of hardcoded numbers/characters (like \u003F = ? ) , when I print, I am getting corresponding character. But in the case of 1, I want it to be 1, but here I am getting some non printable character.

Comment: @bikali I think I should try a different approach to the problem. All I am trying to do is create Hex message like String( new byte[]{(byte)0x2,(byte)0x53, (byte)0x31, (byte)0xEE} ), but dynamically as explained in my previous comments. I thought handling it as string would be easier for concatenation. But it became harder and harder. :(

Comment: @user3124284 When you say "But in the case of 1, I want it to be 1", do you mean byte 0x01 or 0x31?  If the former, then (char)var is what you want (and it will be an unprintable character).  If the latter, then Long.toHexString(var) is what you want (and it will only be possible to represent 0-9a-f in a single byte/char, and everything else will be 2 or more bytes/chars).